# PHP function to hide CSS and Javascript does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

Remove CSS and JavaScript with a PHP function like this:

```
function disable_files() {
    wp_dequeue_style('blocks'); 
    wp_dequeue_style('library');
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-js' );   
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_files', 100); }
```

When I use this function in function.php nothing happens. Is there something missing in the script?

Comment: You would need to include `function.php` as well as any html for us to have any clue as to what's going on. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "*Is there something missing in the script?*" How is `disable_files()` being invoked? Right now, you're invoking `add_action` to hook the `wp_enqueue_scripts` event, but that's *within* your `disable_files()` function. You seem to have a very fundamental misunderstanding of how these hooks work and how to implement them in practice.

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner and am still familiarizing myself with the subject. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

deregister was missing

```
function disable_files() {
    wp_dequeue_style('blocks');
    wp_dequeue_style('library');
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery-js');
    wp_deregister_style('blocks');
    wp_deregister_style('library');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery-js');  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_files', 9999 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'disable_files', 9999 );
```